# SELECT WHERE Statement

Tags: php, ionic-framework

I am trying to select the a value from the database such as

```
 $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT acc_id FROM account_info WHERE acc_id = (the most recent value entered ');
```

i tried :

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT acc_id FROM account_info WHERE acc_id = "26" ');
```

and it was successful. However whenever I try something like  :

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT acc_id FROM account_info WHERE acc_id = :acc_id');
```

or

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT acc_id FROM account_info WHERE acc_id = $acc_id ');
```

i get the following error :

```
core.js:1350 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

my TS code :

```
load()
{
this.http.get('http://localhost:10080/ionic/patients.php')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data =>
  {
     this.items = data;
  });
 }

  viewEntry(param)
{
 this.navCtrl.push('AccInfoPage',param);
}
```

and this is my HTML:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
<h2>{{ item.acc_id }} </h2>
<button ion-button color="primary" item-right (click)="viewEntry({ account: item })">View</button>
 </ion-item>
```

What am I doing wrong ? How can I fix it ??
 Thank you in advance!

Comment: `SELECT acc_id FROM account_info ORDER BY acc_id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Thank you for replying! I tried it it returned the value but not where it is supposed to but in `http://localhost:10080/ionic/patients.php`

Comment: As we have no idea where it's supposed to be returning the value, it's pretty difficult to help you any further

Comment: I apologize i updated my Question

Comment: we dont have access to your localhost

Comment: @nogad i know that it showed up here in this form : `[{"acc_id":74}]`

Comment: You should try logging your json_encode result with error_log($myjson) and then die and then checking if it is correctly formed.

Comment: i removed some unnecessarily code and it did show up where it is supposed to but the id was for the one before it. However at the same time in my localhost the id was correct

Comment: @MarkBaker would you like to post your answer sir and i can choose it as the solution? `SELECT acc_id FROM account_info ORDER BY acc_id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: @MarkBaker i was just testing it and sometimes it gives me the value before the last one entered how can I fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT acc_id FROM account_info ORDER BY acc_id DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create and execute a prepared statement, you need to prepare the query first, bind parameters and then execute.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT acc_id FROM account_info WHERE acc_id = :acc_id');
$stmt->execute([':acc_id' => 26]);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: `SELECT acc_id FROM account_info ORDER BY acc_id DESC LIMIT 1` worked but the value showed up http://localhost:10080/ionic/patients.php